# Cannot install GNOME extensions

Tags: gnome

Currently having issues installing gnome extensions via their website. Usually there is a SLIDER bar that says ON/OFF , but I am unable to see it.

I am running Firefox 28.0 along with UBUNTU 12.04. I have disabled all addons and still nto able to see anything. I have GNOME 3.4.1 installed and GNOME Tweak Tool as well. I am able to install GNOME extensions from the terminal when i know the exact adress or command line.

Also, when I view the webiste it looks like the plugin list icons are sort of grayed out or transparent. When I compare this to screenshot below, they are much brighter and this makes me wonder if this indicates a problem.

Here is the normal image:
[image]

Here is what I see:

[image]

I have read [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions) with no luck

Thanks for reading.

Comment: >I have gnome 3.4.1 installed and gnome tweak tool as well.

Comment: How about you try using another browser for the 'install them via the website' part

Comment: which one would be best to install?I would need something light that is not going to leave residual files all over the place once i remove it?

Comment: You can try chromium from the software center.

Comment: there must be another way to install these extensions without the slider bar no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have to credit Seth for this really, but I was not aware that I had to log out after installing gnome shell, so what I did was this:

[image: Valid XHTML].

after that I was able to see the slider on the extensions website.

Thank you Seth!